# Protobuf map keeps allocating new elements to arena

Tags: memory, protocol-buffers

I have code that updates the values of a protobuf map periodically. This code is simplified for clarity.

```
void my_periodically_called_function() {
    my_protobuf_map->Clear();
    MyObject obj;
    obj.set_value(data);
    my_protobuf_map['my_key'] = obj;
}
```

What happens is that the program memory keeps growing every iteration. After digging through protobuf's map.h it seems that after clearing the map and re-adding elements, [] will just allocate more data to the arena (without clearing any older data) which is obviously undesirable.

What is the most protobuf friendly way to resolve this? I want a good way to be able to delete specific memory from the arena.

An easy way to fix the problem would be to remove the Clear() but I'd like to keep that to avoid weird bugs with old state persisting.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The way protobuf C++ library implements arena allocation, there is no way to free an individual piece of memory. Instead, all of it is freed at once by freeing the whole arena.

The main point of arena allocator is to improve speed by making allocation a constant-time operation (it just increments a pointer).

In your case, it sounds like you'll either want to periodically free the arena and reconstruct the message, or otherwise use the heap allocator which handles freeing memory.